# Create route login for each company's admin

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, authentication, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create login route url for each company admin's profile.

Earlier I tried with same approach when there was single schema. Now I am trying the same in nested structure and finding it little difficult.

Now I want my route url to be like this :- `router.post('/:compId/admin/login')`

I have very less idea as it is new for me to create route for each document.

**My controller:-**

```
var admin = new Admin();
    admin.companyName = req.body.companyName;
    admin.address = req.body.address;
    admin.contactDetails  = req.body.contactDetails;
    admin.admins = {
                  email : req.body.email,
                  password: req.body.password, 
                  firstName : req.body.firstName, 
                  lastName : req.body.lastName,
                  phoneNumber : req.body.phoneNumber,
                  designation : req.body.designation,
                  role : "admin",
                  verified :"false",
                  users: []
    };
```

This is what I tried in **route login:-**

```
router.post('/:compId/admin/login' , (req, res, next) => {

    Admin.find({'admins.email': req.body.email},{ 'admins.companyId': req.params.compId })
    .exec()
    .then(admin => {
        if(admin.admins.length < 1) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: "Auth failed. admin not found."
            })
        }
        bcryptt.compare(req.body.admins.password, admin.admins[0].password, (err, result) =>{
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                message: "Auth failed. Check email and password"
                });             
            }                   
            if (result && admin.admins[0].verified === "true"){
                const adminEmaill = "rgg@xyz.com";                                                  //assaigning a user to admin 
                const role1 = admin.admins[0].email===adminEmaill? "superadmin" : "admin";                                  //check user id as admin or user
                const token = jwt.sign( 
                    {
                        email: admin.admins[0].email,
                        phoneNo: admin.admins[0].phoneNumber,
                        role1,
                        comID: admin.admins[0].companyID
                    },
                    process.env.JWT_KEY,
                    {
                        expiresIn : "1h"
                    });
                    return res.status(200).json({
                    message: "Auth Successful",
                    token : token
                    }); 
            }
            else{
                console.log("admin is not verified");   
                return res.json({
                message: "Admin is not verified"
                }); 
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        if (err.code == 500)
                    res.status(500).send(["Something went wrong in login"]);
            else
            return next(err);
    }); 
});
```

**And my response datas :-**

```
[{
    "admins": {
        "email": "angjun.34@test-mail.info",
        "password": "$2a$10$QgCJ4IaYXZK9JZIkLv2X9O/wnFpn0LEhFQujBco0M0TF2.X7OgDmW",
        "firstName": "hdsdsds",
        "lastName": "Ghodsdsdsh",
        "phoneNumber": "4544343",
        "designation": "Software Engineer",
        "role": "admin",
        "verified": "false",
        "users": [],
        "emailResetTokenn": "247c6e6794d15a311670da0bb13a4a8bf773b0e7f7b5dde0e555f421e2aef22f",
        "emailExpires": "2019-05-22T15:05:43.974Z",
        "saltSecret": "$2a$10$QgCJ4IaYXZK9JZIkLv2X9O"
    },
    "_id": "5ce510e7aca42c4c74fd9085",
    "companyName": "TEST",
    "address": "UAE",
    "contactDetails": "54534454",
    "companyID": "1223365",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "admins": {
        "email": "groham.224@test-mail.info",
        "password": "$2a$10$QgCJ9O/wnFpn0LEhFco0M0TF2.X7OgDmW",
        "firstName": "hdsdsds",
        "lastName": "Ghodsdsdsh",
        "phoneNumber": "4544343",
        "designation": "Software Engineer",
        "role": "admin",
        "verified": "false",
        "users": [],
        "emailResetTokenn": "247c6e6794d15a311670da0bb13a4a8bf773b0e7f7b5dde0e555f421e2aef22f",
        "emailExpires": "2019-05-22T15:05:43.974Z",
        "saltSecret": "$2a$10$QgCJ4IaYXZK9JZIkLv2X9O"
    },
    "_id": "5ce510e7aca42c4c74fd9085",
    "companyName": "RESTFUL Pvt Ltd",
    "address": "UK",
    "contactDetails": "54534454",
    "companyID": "155165",
    "__v": 0
}]
```

### Question

- So how will create `login` for each of these companies admin's `router.post('/:compId/admin/login')` so that only the object of respective company's details can pass in **JWT** when login ? The login route that I have added is not working.

***Example:-*** Suppose for second company route will be `('/155165/admin/login')`

Comment: You already answered `/155165/admin/login`, I do not understand what is your question, can you rephrase it again?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam How can I query this ? I have added my login function. It is not working.

Comment: your code seems fine, what is the error? at `route login`?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam I am not getting jwt token in response. When I am testing it in POSTMAN , `{baseurl}/155165/admin/login` with email pass as body , nothing is showing up.

Comment: Okay, Something breaks so do not debug code blindly, Use debugger for example. 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging 
  debug code line by line and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using the wrong query **`companyID` is not a child of `admins`**

So query should be

```
Admin.find({'admins.email': req.body.email},{ 'companyID': req.params.compId })
```

Comment: try to debug? I think ` Admin.find(` return empty data

Comment: This returns me `Mongoose: admins.find({ 'admins.email': rgba4_ee@info.com' }, { projection: { companyId: '1556165' } })`

Comment: Try this `Admin.find({'admins.email': req.body.email, 'companyID': req.params.compId})`

Comment: No nothing happened . `Mongoose: admins.find({ 'admins.email': 'gopa@mailsource.info', companyID: '155165' }, { projection: {} })`